# What do these git symbols mean?

Tags: git

In git, what does the at symbol and curly braces mean?

```
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
```

Likewise, what do double hyphens mean? Not as an option, but as used like so:

```
git checkout abcd1234 -- .
```

I'm sure this is referenced somewhere obvious, but I'm having a hard time finding it. Also, searching for non-alphanumeric symbols is difficult.

Comment: Upvoted for spelling out the symbol names so this could be found via a web search

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The at and curly braces are documented in the [`gitrevisions` manual page](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

In your example, it means the prior value of the `HEAD` ref - whatever commit `HEAD` pointed to before your most recent commit or checkout or whatever.

The double hyphens separate flags from non-flags (usually filenames, but sometimes other things like branch names or remote names).  You can use `--` to make sure git doesn't treat the argument after the `--` as a flag, in case it might look like one.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be one the most impossible questions to try and Google for. Google ignores most symbols and likes to interpret git as a misspelling of get. :D

Comment: Yep.  I knew there was a man page covering this but I had to grep in `/usr/share/doc/git-doc` to remember what it was called!

Comment: More up-to-date URL: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions